# Provide name of an attribute rather than the ID

Tags: sql

So the issue I am having is I need to provide the name of a team, but I am not able to do so without providing the teamid as well. This is the code I have currently along with the output:

use football

select teamid, teamname

from team

except

select winning_team

, teamname

from game g join team t

on g.winning_team = t.teamid

```
 teamid teamname

    100 No Winner      
    107 Red Tigers
```

(2 rows affected)

and the output I need is:

### teamName

No Winner
Red Tigers

Any ideas?

Comment: `select teamname` instead of `select teamid, teamname`?

Comment: Provide the actual SQL you have problem with.

Answer (score 0):

if the seemingly obvious `select teamname` doesn't work for some reason, you can wrap your query inside another query:

```
select 
    teamname
from (
    select
        teamid, 
        teamname
    from 
        team
    except
        select
            winning_team
            , teamname
        from 
            game g 
            join team t on g.winning_team = t.teamid
) as myquery
```

Comment: The issue with removing teamid from select is that the except is trying to compare the ID found in teamid to the ID found in winning_team